Propagating the Darboux / Frenet-Serret frame on a sphere or general surface
Approaching this question as an engineer so apologies for any misunderstanding.
Given $\gamma(t)$ as a unit-speed curve residing on the two-sphere $S^{2}$, we can define a Darboux frame and by applying the Frenet-Serret equations, generate equivalent equations using the geodesic curvature $\kappa_{g}$, normal curvature $\kappa_n$ and geodesic torsion $\tau_g$. $$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{T}\\\mathbf{t}\\\mathbf{u}\end{bmatrix}=u\begin{bmatrix}0&\kappa_{g}&\kappa_{n}\\-\kappa_{g}&0&\tau_{g}\\-\kappa_{n}&\tau_{g}&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{T}\\\mathbf{t}\\\mathbf{u}\end{bmatrix}$$
I'd like to be able to use these equations to propagate a point on the sphere. For curves $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ we can write $$\frac{d}{dt}x=u\mathbf{T}$$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$.
Would this equation also apply for the general case of a curve on a surface (interested in $S^{2}$)? Specifically, would the position retain the unitary constraint?
Thanks in advance!
